# Offline symbol server over http

Tags: http, iis, windbg, symbols

I'm currently trying to set up an offline symbols server that will serve up symbols much the same as Microsoft's own symbol server works.

In essence, I would like to have the ability to use 'srv*C:\symbolcache*http://my.symbol.server' as my symbol path in windbg.  I have IIS up and running and added a MIME type for .pdb files.

I used symstore to add the symbols from various flavors of Windows and then updated my symbols bath in windbg to no avail.

Since I'm using several different OSes, the symbols directory just contains .PTR files to the actual location of the .pdb -- which I think is my problem.

As an example, in my symbols folder I have a folder called 'mswrd6.pdb' which contains 4 directories that are all 32 character hex, each one of those directories contains a "file.ptr" file which points to the correct location of the desired .pdb.

Long story short, does anyone know of a guide or documentation out there that goes through how to create a symbols server over http?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the guide I used when I setup my symbol server. It takes a fair amount of fiddling with to get everything to work. But this guide along with Google should get you the whole way.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681417(VS.85).aspx